# CSS Opacity not showing up in Chrome but in JSFiddle

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, opacity

I've been trying to get my menu to show up as transparent on my local server. However, it keeps showing up as a solid background. I load the code into JSFiddle and it shows up as transparent. I flushed my cache and switched browsers - but the problem persists. Any ideas about what's happening? (I don't know if this is causing a conflict, but I'm also using the latest version of Bootstrap)

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CJYGb/
Screenshot (local): https://i.stack.imgur.com/z27Up.jpg

Code:

HTML:

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar-home navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header"><a href="/" class="navbar-brand"><img src="images/logo.png"></a></div>
        <div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
html {
  background: url("http://blog.jimdo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tree-247122.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.navbar-home {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(200,54,54,0.5);
  height: 80px;
  padding: 0;
}
.container-fluid {
  max-width: 1080px;
  height: 80px;
}
.container-fluid a {
  padding: 0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 80px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a:hover {
  color: #151515;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

Comment: Is there any other css which is affecting navbar? See in browser console for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this behaviour is due to some `background-color` style which are applied on body.
If there is any rule which applies `background-color` to body in your local server, then that is causing the issue.

I added a `background-color:#FFFF` to body and it's similar to what you have in the screenshot

```
body { background:#FFFFFF; }
```

**Demo with background color**: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/CJYGb/2/

If you remove the `background-color` from body css or give `background-color:none` then you'll have the necessary opacity.

**Demo without background color** : http://jsfiddle.net/CJYGb/

Comment: Your intuition was right! Seems like Bootstrap by default adds in colors to the navbar. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you use tranparent PNG?

```
.navbar-home {
background-image:url('transparent.png');
background-repeat:repeat;
}
```